# How can I stop data:post.snippet from stripping away HTML tags?

Tags: css

I have a small blog about typography, and it's thus quite frustrating that `data:post.snippet` in CSS strips away all formatting (eg `<em>` ).  Is there a way to make snippets include original HTML tags?

Comment: you have to provide more context, what's that `data:post.snippet`? it's not standard CSS, and you first talk about formatting but than about tags, is the tag there with missing formatting or the tag is not even there?

Comment: sounds like you are using some kind of blog building application/system like Jekyll, probably that application is stripping away tags when you call `post.snippet`, it's not a CSS issue and it's probably how that application works

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.